# Prove the integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Prove that :
$
\mathop{\int}\limits_{L}{\frac{dz}{{z}^{2}\mathrm{{+}}{1}}}\mathrm{{=}}{0}
$

If $
L
$
 is an arbitrary closed rectifiable curve contained in the annulus $
{1}\mathrm{{<}}\left|{z}\right|\mathrm{{<}}{R}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{(}}{R}\mathrm{{>}}{1}{\mathrm{)}}
$

but not if $
L
$
 is an arbitrary closed rectifiable curve contained in the domain consisting of all points such that $
{z}^{2}\mathrm{{+}}{1}\rlap{/}{\mathrm{{=}}}{0}{\mathrm{.}}
$

Answer (score 0):

As $L$ is compact, $dist(L, \partial D(0,1))>0$ and so $L \subset D:= \Bbb C\setminus \overline{D(0,1)}$, on which $z \mapsto \frac1{z^2+1}$ is holomorphic and so Cauchy's integral theorem applies.

If $L$ is just in $\Bbb C\setminus \{-1,1\}$, it can't necessarily be put inside a domain on which the map is holomorphic, and Cauchy's integral theorem doesn't apply. Try for a counterexample $L=\partial D(1, 1/2)$.

Comment: i have a hint but still i dont know how i will use it   $
\frac{1}{{z}^{2}\mathrm{{+}}{1}}\mathrm{{=}}\frac{1}{2i}\left({\frac{1}{{z}\mathrm{{-}}{i}}\mathrm{{-}}\frac{1}{{z}\mathrm{{+}}{i}}}\right)
$

Comment: can you help me in that ?

Answer (score 0):

Given your hint, I think the book wants you to use a corollary from Cauchy's integral formula. 
$$\int_L \frac{dz}{z-a} = \pm 2\pi i$$
$\pm$ depends on the orientation of L, if $a \in int(L)$.
Given this, I think it is obvious that the above integral evaluates to $0$.